# importing large csv file to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

As all suggested load data local infile i also used the same query but i am getting error.

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE   '/home/invensis/phygital_visualize/csv/originalcsv/lic.csv'
INTO TABLE  li
FIELDS TERMINATED by ’,’
LINES TERMINATED BY ’n’
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

the error is

```
 MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '’,’
LINES TERMINATED BY ’n’
IGNORE 1 ROWS' at line 3
```

csv file looks like this

```
    NAME,JOB TITLE,DEPARTMENT,EMPLOYEE ANNUALSALARY,ESTIMATEDANNUALSALARYMINUSFURLOUGHS
"AARON,  ELVIA J",WATER RATE TAKER,WATER MGMNT,$81000.00,$73862.00
"AARON,  JEFFERY M",POLICE OFFICER,POLICE,$74628.00,$74628.00
"AARON,  KIMBERLEI R",CHIEF CONTRACT EXPEDITER,FLEET MANAGEMNT,$77280.00,$70174.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you - you've used `’` instead of `'` in the SQL - just go and edit those quotes!

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE   '/home/invensis/phygital_visualize/csv/originalcsv/lic.csv'
INTO TABLE  li
FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Also note you probably intended the termination to be `\n` rather than a literal `n`

Answer (score 0):

Use " instead of ´:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE   '/home/invensis/phygital_visualize/csv/originalcsv/lic.csv'
INTO TABLE  li
FIELDS TERMINATED by ","
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Also be aware that for security reasons, mysql only allows importing csvs from specific locations, such as /tmp: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data-local.html